# What's the best way to display a PDF file in community builder?

Tags: community, pdf, content, salesforce-cms

I have a pdf file that I'd like users to be able to open from their home landing page. I've tried using CMS in community builder, but the content just comes up as a big white or grey box.

I went into content management, created a CMS workspace, and uploaded the file. I also tried making a collection. Nothing appears whether I use CMS Single Object or CMS Collection and select this content.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the best way to display a pdf on a community page? If possible, I'd like the pdf's first page to be visible as a preview and then clicking on it would open the full pdf in another tab.

Comment: what's the performance impact on page load? can you load the file to external document storage system like s3 and display the preview of the file from s3 using a LWC? or load the file to salesforce and https://sfdcpanther.com/how-to-preview-files-in-lightning-community-using-lwc/

Answer (score 2):

This does not completely answer the question but it might still be worth checking the Salesforce Experience Cloud blog post
[How to use CMS Documents Like a Pro in your Experience Cloud Site](https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/How-to-use-CMS-Documents-Like-a-Pro-in-your-Experience-Cloud-Site) which describes how to setup CMS document for use in Experience cloud.

Once setup, the page shows a button or link to dowload the document and note the conclusion of the blog in the summary :

> **CMS Documents** are a great way to share documents with all users of your site in a visually beautiful fashion. **It doesn’t have all the bells and whistles that Salesforce Files offers** (e.g. advanced sharing, **file preview**, searching inside the document, etc.) so it is best used for a small number of documents that your users will browse and might download as part of a call to action.

Furthermore, the [CMS Content Types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cms_customcontenttypes.htm&type=5) documentation mentions this

> **The preview function is available for image content types only in a CMS workspace** or from a Lightning Experience site page. This limitation applies to CMS Single Item and CMS Collection components.

Alternative is to go for a custom development solution to preview the file in an LWC component as @cl11 mentioned in the comments